# Xcode support special character

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am currently packaging an application with Xcode 12 and when I put an apostrophe in the Product Name, I get the following error:
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"

How do I authorize apostrophes?

I have several configurations per environment

Comment: Where exactly are you putting the ' ?  It sounds like you are putting it in a field that isn't supported. The bundle display name is seperate to the package name.

Comment: I put it in the Build Settings => Product Name section.

Comment: I assume that is a flutter thing. I don't know how that maps to the fields in Xcode. You can definitely have an apostrophe in the "display name" which maps to the bundle display name in the info.plist. You will probably need to generate your flutter project without the apostrophe and then modify the resulting info.plist file

Comment: the field name provided is what is in XCode. But otherwise how to handle multiple info.plist because I have multiple environment